# Arrange formatted fields in Views row using a template

Tags: 7, views, entities

I want to render the rows of my “Recent content” Views page using a template in order to

- subdivide the rows into multiple divs,
- freely move around the rendered fields within these divs, and
- apply some custom PHP where needed.

**Idea A (fails):** I could achieve this by creating a new Display Suite layout for nodes and using this layout to render my view set to display format “Content”. However, I need to group the rows by a specific field, and grouping by fields is not available in the “Content” display format – for this, I would need to chose the display format “Fields”.

**Idea B (fails):** When displaying fields (say, as an unformatted list), I can make use a copy of

- views-view.tpl.php to adjust the coarse layout of the view, e.g., put an additional div around the whole content block;
- views-view-fields.tpl.php to adjust how a single field should be rendered;
- views-view-unformatted.tpl.php to adjust the coarse layout of rows, e.g. put 
  an additional div around the whole row. However, here the $row variable is not an array of rendered fields but rather a string containing the full html markup of the row, so I cannot access single fields and move them around within the row as I wish.

**Idea C (works, but isn't it extremely inefficient?):** I could display an unformatted list of fields, but render only the Node-ID-field. Then, in views-view-unformatted.tpl.php I can load the whole node corresponding to the current row via $node = node_load($row); and access all fields attached to it via $node->field_whatever. These I can then move around as I wish, wrap in divs, and apply custom PHP.

Idea C seems to work, but it also seems highly inefficient, as I will have to load the full node for every row. Also, I want to leverage the many views display formatters that my fields come equipped with, which I would have to re-build manually.

**Question:** Is there a way to specify formats for specific fields within the Views UI, submit only these to a template (and not the whole node), and move them around freely within the row as explained above?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and this is what I did.

Let's say for the sake of argument that we have 6 fields: A to F. I wanted to wrap A-C in a layer eg "col-1" and D-F in a second layer eg "col-2". I overrided the field templates (`views-view-fields--field-*.tpl.php`) for A, C, D, F as such:

- Added a `<div class="col-1">` element in A, **without a matching closing tag** `</div>`.
- Added a `<div class="col-2">` element in D, **without a matching closing tag** `</div>`.
- Added the respective closing tags `</div>` i n **C and F**.

This may show some error or warning in your IDE, but the rendered HTML should be ok **as long as the order of the fields in the views allows it** (eg don't re-arrange D to be above C).